# Powering difference between different Raspberry Pi 4 models

Tags: power-supply, pi-4

Raspberry Pi 4 has three models which have 1GB, 2GB, and 4GB of RAM. Is there any difference between these models for powering?

Comment: Any difference would be negligible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is, *"The Foundation"* has not published any specifications on it. It's clear that there will be **some** increase in power consumption with more RAM, but from 1 to 4 GB this is almost certainly a small additional load.

Also, [*"The Foundation's"* published figures for power consumption across all models of Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/faqs/#pi-power) shows only a single figure for RPi 4B: 3.0 Amps at 5 VDC. They (*"The Foundation"*) do not delineate different figures for different RAM configurations. One would ordinarily assume that the published figure of 3.0 Amps would cover the "worst case" power consumption from the 4 GB configuration. Assumptions regarding *"The Foundation's"* designs and hardware documentation should be made with an extra measure of caution, but in this case it seems safe to assume that a 5V 3A power supply (that meets the USB specifications for line & load regulation) will power the 1 GB, 2 GB and 4 GB configurations.